# Using iterator in underscoreGS functions

Tags: google-apps-script

Can anybody write basic example using iterator in functions like `_any()`, `_all()`, ... of the underscoreGS library? Like this:

```
function myFunction() {
  var arr = [1, 3, 0, -1, 4];
  // are all values greater than 0 ?
  Logger.log(underscoreGS._all(arr, iterator???, >0???);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the iteration functions on the Array object? Something like the following:

```
function foo() {
    var arr = [1, 3, 0, -1, 4];

    Logger.log(arr.every(function(item) {
        return item > 0;
    }));
}
```

Here are a list of iterator functions you can use on Arrays in Google Apps Script:

- [`Array::every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)
- [`Array::some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)
- [`Array::map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`Array::reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [`Array::reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight)
- [`Array::forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Google Apps Script does not natively support [`Array::filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) or [`Array::find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), but you can always use the polyfills from Mozilla's developer documentation.

---

**UPDATE**

GAS now natively supports the [`Array::filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function.